# How to parse a string containing a calculation and execute it

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have following situation

So I have an object something like this

```
var y = {
  "data": {
    "m": 2,
    "n": "meaow",
    "k": "lop",
    "r": {
      "val": 400,
      "text": "Hoila papi"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to give my user to write a formula which I can parse based on that object 
something like this

```
var  x = {
            "calculation": "((@data>m# * 100) + (@data>r>val# / 200))",
            "target": "data>m"
 }
```

Is there a way this is possible to do in Javascript
so the final result should be

```
{
  "data": {
    "m": 202,
    "n": "meaow",
    "k": "lop",
    "r": {
      "val": 400,
      "text": "Hoila papi"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't `((@data>m# * 100) + (@data>r>val# / 200))` = 20002?

Comment: @GiorgioBozio sorry :) yes

Comment: @GiorgioBozio  What should be an appropriate heading for this question so that other developers could use it , As you are senior in reputation so i ask the questio :)

Comment: how about something like "How to parse a string containing a calculation and execute it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match the `@prop>prop...` strings, and replace them with the appropriate value by using `reduce` on the property array. Assuming the input is trustworthy, you can then `eval` the resulting math string, and use the same `reduce` method to find the nested object to update.

Note that `((200 * 100) + (400 / 200))` results in `20002`, not `202`:

```js
var y = {
  "data": {
    "m": 200,
    "n": "meaow",
    "k": "lop",
    "r": {
      "val": 400,
      "text": "Hoila papi"
    }
  }
}

var x = {
  "calculation": "((@data>m# * 100) + (@data>r>val# / 200))",
  "target": "data>m"
};
const getNested = (propArr, initial) => propArr.reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], initial);
const mathStr = x.calculation.replace(/@(\S+)#/g, (_, propStr) => (
  Number(getNested(propStr.split('>'), y))
));
console.log(mathStr);
if (/[^-+/*0-9() ]/.test(mathStr)) {
  throw new Error('Unrecognized, potentially unsafe character found');
}

const targetPropArr = x.target.split('>');
const lastProp = targetPropArr.pop();
const lastObj = getNested(targetPropArr, y);
lastObj[lastProp] = eval(mathStr);

console.log(y);
```

Comment: Thanks used similar approach in PHP for backend wasn't sure about front end thanks for the code , i am going to try to understand it and then implement